# Propertly would not be serialize into a Parcel in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions

I wish to have my variables **that are not** from my constructor, part of my Parcelable.
However, I face this warning "Propertly would not be serialize into a Parcel", that inform me I can't do that currently.

I am using Kotlin in *experimental* v.1.2.41.

How can I do ?

```
@Parcelize
data class MyClass(private val myList: List<Stuff>) : Parcelable {

    val average: List<DayStat> by lazy {
        calculateAverage(myList)
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you want to make it a part of `Parcelable` (just mark `@Transient`) or to write it to the parcel?

In the second case [the design document](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/extensions/android-parcelable.md) explains why this is a problem (search for "Properties with initializers declared in the class body") and laziness only makes the meaning less clear.

If you can live without laziness, you can do this:

```
@Parcelize
data class MyClass (private val myList: List<Stuff>, val average: List<DayStat> = calculateAverage(myList)) : Parcelable {
    ...
}
```